# how to handle props between components in react

Tags: reactjs, mern

i have came accross a problem where i am passing three props to a component  **Landingheader** from parent **Landing.js**  now i have another component called **Cart** and i want to use **LandingHeader**
as child component inside **Cart** but then i would also have to pass all the three props again to Landingheader which is very difficult and alot of code to rewrite

here is the code in Landing.js

```
 <div>
      <Landingheader
        fetchproductResults={fetchproductResults}
        user={user}
        cartValue={cartValue}
      />
```

above you can see landingHeader component is getting three differenct props

here is my cart component  where i want to resuse landingHeader component

```
import { Fragment } from "react";
import Landingheader from "./landingHeader";

const Cart = () => {
    return ( 

<Fragment>
<Landingheader />



</Fragment>

     );
}
 
export default Cart;
```

so above the landingHeader will now require three props so this means i would have to rewrite the whole logic again? how to solve this propblem? thanks

**code for  fetchproductResults**

```
  const fetchproductResults = (keyword) => {
    setWord(keyword);
    if (keyword !== "") {
      const searchedRs = allproducts.filter((eachproduct) => {
        return Object.values(eachproduct)
          .join("")
          .toLowerCase("")
          .includes(keyword.toLowerCase());
      });

      setResult(searchedRs);
    } else {
      setResult(allproducts);
    }
  };
```

Answer (score 0):

In case you don't need to pass any props to `Landingheader` from `Cart` you could use default value props in `Landingheader`. Something like:

```
const Landingheader = (props) => {
    const { fetchproductResults = [], user = "", cartValue = "" } = props;
    return (...);
}

export default Landingheader;
```

Comment: thanks but in Cart.js where i am resuing the Landingheader it will require 3 props how will i provide it its code is in landing.js page

Comment: @nodeDev In this case you could replicate the logic (bad) or you need to store 3 props somewhere to reuse them. The best approach is [Redux](https://redux.js.org/) to have all the state variables you need everywhere. But in your case could be overskilled. Have you tried to store `fetchproductResults, user and cartValue` in `localStorage`?

Comment: the problem is that the landingHeader page will be used in many different pages so geting theses three in every will required alot of time and effort currently  i am using method i have  successfully passed two values to cart component like this     <Link    to={{pathname: "/cart",state: { user,cartValue},  }} the values i am getting in Landingheader i passed it  here to cart route and then get it again in cart props and then pass it again to Landingheader  in cart.js

Comment: @nodeDev Definitively you have to use Redux. I strongly suggest you to spent couple of hours to understand Redux.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `context` instead of `props`

in **Landing** component:

```
const MyContext=createContext(null)

const Landing=()=>{
     .......
    return (<MyContext.Provider value={[fetchproductResults,user,cartValue]}>
      ... all child compoenents
            </MyContext.Provider/>
```

Now in **Landingheader** :

```
const [fetchproductResults,user,cartValue]=useContext(MyContext)  /// use them as you like
```

Now you don't need to pass any props to either Cart or LandingHeader, it is receiving the data through context.

Comment: thanks alot , i guess you are using some advanced stuff here maybe Context api , i only know the name , so i have tried this way of getting passing the values   <Link    to={{pathname: "/cart",state: { user,cartValue},  }} and it worked but there is one fucntion that needs to be passed as well  fetchproductResults its giving error

Comment: that's also a good idea actually. what error is it showing?

Comment: the fetchproductResults  is actually a function in Landing.js page which i passed to Landingheader.js along with cartValue and user , now that i have to reuse the Landingheader in Cart component i  got the cartValue and user through methid i  shared earlier but the fetchproductResults is a function and its logic is in Landing.js page thats why it is giving error like --->pushState' on 'History': keyword => {
    setWord(keyword);

    if (keyword !== "") {
      const searchedRs = ...........etc etc

Comment: i have shared the code for  fetchproductResults  in my post kindly check it thanks